# JS function returning empty value to input box

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-models, dom-events

When the list-item-action class button is select or is active I want to appear a name in the `skill_category` input box and then send it to the models of my website.

This code is not giving a name of list-item.

It is returning an empty value in the `skill_category` input in my form:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.list-group-item-action').click(function() {


    if ($('.list-group-item-action').hasclass('active')) {

      var cat_txt = "";

      $('.list-group-item-action').each(function() {
        cat_txt += $(this).val()
      });

      $('#cat_txt').val(txt);
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="list-group" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-lead_generator-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-lead_generator" role="tab" aria-controls="lead_generator" value="Lead generator"><i class='fas fa-users'></i>Lead generator</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-content_creator-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-content_creator" role="tab" aria-controls="content_creator" value="Content Creator"><i class='fas fa-pen'></i>Content Creator</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-social-social_media_handler-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-social_media_handler" role="tab" aria-controls="social_media_handler" value="Social Media Handler"><i class='fas fa-icons'></i>Social Media Handler</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
      {% comment %} <input class="bg-white rounded border border-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 text-base px-4 py-2 mb-4" placeholder="Skill" name="Skill" type="text"> {% endcomment %}

      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list-lead_generator" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-lead_generator-list">
        <label class="container">Lead Generator
                      <input type="checkbox"  name="lead_generator" value='Lead Generator' class="lead_generator">
                      <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<form method="post">

  {% csrf_token %}


  <input type='text' name="user" class="user" value="{{user.username}}" />
  <input type="text" name="skill_category" id="cat_txt" class="skill_category">
  <input type="text" name="skill" id="txt" class="skill">
  <div class='container nxtbtn'>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning"> Next Page </button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Here are my models.py

models.py

```
class Skill(models.Model):
  user = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  skill_category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  skill = models.CharField(max_length=500)

  def __str__(self):
     return self.user
```

and here is my views

views.py

```
def skillsSelect(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    
    saveskill = Skill()
    saveskill.user = request.POST.get('user')
    saveskill.skill_category = request.POST.get('skill_category')
    saveskill.skill = request.POST.get('skill')
    saveskill.save()

    return render(request, 'growithkaizen/skillsSelect.html')

 else:
    return render(request, 'growithkaizen/skillsSelect.html')
```

Comment: You have typo `hasclass` should be `hasClass` i.e `C`. Also , where is name which you need to get ?

Comment: I have changed hasclass to hasClass but then also the input is not coming

Comment: which value should be come where it is?

Comment: When list-group-item is active the value of active .list-group-item should be written in the #skill_category input. So that I can store it in the table

Comment: Simply you can write `$('#cat_txt').val($(this).attr('value'));` because your `a` tag has `value` attribute which you need to show that should work.

Comment: where to write this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223414/discussion-between-swati-and-dhruv).

Comment: Yep that works Thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 0):

javaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.list-group-item').click(function() {
        if ( $('.list-group-item').hasClass('active') ) {

           $('#cat_txt').val($(this).attr('value'));

        }
    });
```